# Get list of Images or Blobs in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I get the images or blobs that are embedded in a Google spreadsheet using Google Apps Script? For charts, I'd use Sheet.getCharts() that would return an array of EmbeddedChart type.

It's simple enough to embed an image in the first place using Sheet.insertImage, but I can't access it again?

Comment: Try using the [getImage()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/image-item#getimage) from the [ImageItem class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/image-item) but I think it's for Forms. I didn't see any specific method for  [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)

Answer (score 0):

It is a work around, but might work for you. Set the images with a formula and then change the formula and replace the old one. If there are formulas other than images, you can return only image formulas:

```
function getImages() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getSheets()[0];
  var  str="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_100.jpg"
  var D1=s.getRange("D1").setFormula('=image("'+str+'", 4, 50, 100)')
  var str1="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"
  var E1=s.getRange("E1").setFormula('=image("'+str1+'", 4, 50, 100)')
  var list = s.getDataRange().getFormulas() //get any cells with formulas
  var array=[]
//get array of image formulas only
for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
  for(var j=0;j<list[0].length;j++){
      var ts=list[i][j]
      var sbs=ts.substring(0,6)// get first 6 characters of formula
          if(sbs=="=image"){ // if = '=image'
      array.push(list[i][j])
  }}
  // do what you want to with the list of image formulas to change images. 
}}
```